# Android achartengine How to get 0 on Y axis have padding at bottom

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I have a problem whereby my Y axis minimum is 0, this is good, but I need it to be offset from the bottom a bit, because when there's a sequence of zero values, my X labels are slightly covered by the dot. Also, the X axis line is running through all the points, which looks bad.

Is this possible with achartengine? How can I acheive it? Thank you

Comment: Do you want to move the labels or the axis or something else?

Comment: Hi there, we could not find a way to solve this, so what we did is, customize the symbols on the graph so that if they appear at 0, only the top 50% of the circle is rendered, therefore no overlap exists.